# Is there a word to describe someone who is always defeated at my hand?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions

If A always defeats B, A is B's nemesis.
If B always loses to his rival A, B is A's ____?

Comment: Biyatch? (Sorry)

Comment: What they are called depends on your POV but I know I am the infracaninophile

Comment: Who wouldn't save a puppy in traffic? ;-)

Comment: continual annoyance.

Comment: A "nemesis" means one's arch-enemy, but that doesn't necessarily mean the one who always wins.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? In what way is B not also A's nemesis? So much *antagonism*.

Comment: Clarification: Both A & B were competing in a number of piano competitions and both are highly qualified top contenders. For some reason, A always won. B beat C before in another competition, but A lost to C several times in the past.

Answer (score 4):

B is A's punching bag.

B is A's whipping boy.

Stooge.

Sucker.

Schmuck.

Mark.

"Mark" and "punching bag" are the least offensive. "Mark" is the least informal.

http://thesaurus.com/browse/whipping%20boy

Comment: I agree with @Beta that "whipping boy" means a proxy for punishment. And "whipping boy" has some nice synonyms for the given situation. And "Tottenham use Fulham as a whipping boy" works.

Comment: "Punching bag" would be the best fit, I think -- it directly implies that B is incapable of putting up any resistance in a fight.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best term depends strongly on how the conflict between A and B comes about.

If the weaker B is the instigator of the conflict despite being repeatedly defeated, they might be called a "**challenger**" or "**contender**".

On the other hand, if the stronger A is picking on B who is no threat to them, B might be described as "**victim**", "**goat**", "**whipping-boy**" or any number of other more offensive epithets (including, as Earnest Friedman-Hill commented, variations on "**bitch**").

Comment: "Whipping boy" means a proxy for punishment, not someone who loses every fight.

Comment: Add *perennial*, *traditional*, *usual* or the like to express an ongoing relationship.

Comment: I think that current colloquial usage of the term "whipping boy" is a bit broader than the literal people the dictionary definitions describe. It has to do with why A is beating B. If the fight is one-sided and A gives a contrived explanation for instigating the abuse, you could describe B as a "whipping-boy" because the reasoning for the abuse is just as flimsy as the reasons for beating the historic whipping boys for a prince's bad behavior (we generally don't believe in the Divine Right of Kings these days).

Answer (score 1):

Different words for different settings:

- in a team sport: *cakewalk*
- on the playground: *my bitch*
- funny example: [Washington Generals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Generals)
- an older phrase that still holds up : *patsy*
- gentleman's term: *pawn*
- if player A also wins easily and plays around: *toy* or *puppet*

Comment: A pawn sounds more to me like someone that is on your side, but expendable. Similar with toy or puppet, but those are leaning the right way.

Comment: @Cruncher - that is one definition.  Slang just means someone that you easily control.  Doesn't have to be on your side.

Answer (score 1):

If A always defeats B, A is B's nemesis.
If B always loses to his contender A, B is A's [unfortunate rival](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rival), or simply **"A's rival."**

> **[rival](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rival)**: a person or thing that tries to defeat or be more successful than another.

Answer (score 0):

The one not expected to win — usually based on the previous record — is called the *underdog*.